# mvc 4 model binding does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following controller

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult BorrowBookFinal(string test)
{


    return View();
}
```

I have some Jquery that calls the action

```
function borrowBook(e) {

    debugger;
    var viewModel = {};
    viewModel = { test: "test" };
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(viewModel);

    var url = "/Borrower/BorrowBookFinal";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: jsonData,
        success: borrowBookComplete,
        dataType: "JSON"
    });


}
```

but when I debug the action method, test is always null even though I am passing the value "test", what am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you converting the submitted data to JSON?  the dataType: 'JSON' refers to the type expected for the *response*.  Try submittting viewModel instead of jsonData as the data element in the ajax call.

As a side note your action does not return JSON data either, so you probalby want to change either that or the dataType

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON object directly without converting it to string:

```
function borrowBook(e) {
    debugger;
    var viewModel = {};
    viewModel = { test: "test" };
    var url = "/Borrower/BorrowBookFinal";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: viewModel,
        success: borrowBookComplete
});
}
```